# I cannot figure out what is wrong with the javascript code below. I try to store a function in a variable

Tags: javascript, function, var

I have re-written the entire code according to the suggestions I received, but there seems to be something which I miss as I still cannot use the var deducere in math operations. I get the NaN all the time. Any suggetion on my code would be very helfull as at this point I run out of ideas. And it seems this way is the best way to learn.

```
function calculeazaVenit() {
        var venit_brut = document.getElementById("venit_brut").value;
        var selection = document.getElementById("select1").value;
        var cas = (10.5 / 100) * venit_brut;
        var cass = (5.5 / 100) * venit_brut;
        var somaj = (0.5 / 100) * venit_brut;
        var nr_tichete = document.getElementById("nr_tichete").value;
        var val_tichete = document.getElementById("val_tichete").value;
        var tichete = nr_tichete * val_tichete;
        var impozit = (16 / 100) * (venit + tichete);
        if (venit_brut != null) {
            document.getElementById("venit_brutx").innerHTML = Math.round(venit_brut);
            document.getElementById("cas").innerHTML = Math.round(cas);
            document.getElementById("cass").innerHTML = Math.round(cass);
            document.getElementById("somaj").innerHTML = Math.round(somaj);
            document.getElementById("venitx").innerHTML = Math.round(venit);
            document.getElementById("tichete").innerHTML = Math.round(tichete);
            document.getElementById("impozit").innerHTML = Math.round(impozit);
            document.getElementById("venit_net").innerHTML = Math.round(venit_net);
        }
        };


        function calculateDeducere(selection, venit_brut) {
        var deducere0 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 300;
        var deducere1 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 400;
        var deducere2 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 500;
        var deducere3 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 600;
        var deducere4 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 800;
        if (selection == 0 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
            return 300;
        }
        if (selection == 0 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
            return Math.ceil10(deducere0, 1);
        }
        if (selection == 1 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
            return 400;
        }
        if (selection == 1 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
            return Math.ceil10(deducere1, 1);
        }
        if (selection == 2 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
            return 500;
        }
        if (selection == 2 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
            return Math.ceil10(deducere2, 1);
        }
        if (selection == 3 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
            return 600;
        }
        if (selection == 3 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
            return Math.ceil10(deducere3, 1);
        }
        if (selection == 4 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
            return 800;
        }
        if (selection == 4 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
            return Math.ceil10(deducere4, 1);
        }
        if (document.getElementById("btn_deducere").checked == false) {
            document.getElementById("deducerex").innerHTML = 0;
        }
        if (venit_brut > 3000)  {
        return 0;
        }
        };

    var deducere = calculateDeducere(selection, venit_brut);
    var venit = venit_brut - (cas + cass + somaj + deducere);
    var venit_net = venit - impozit + deducere;

        document.getElementById("deducerex").innerHTML = Math.round(deducere);
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: You need some serious refactor

Comment: Where are the selection and venit_brut variables being set? where is the deducere() function called? Please include any additional code you have. There is not enough here to debug. Or, if this is all you have, you never call this function and you don't set the variables it uses.

Comment: `foo` is undefined the first time you use it (assuming the `var foo = function() ...` part is placed before, you are creating a function and never calling it (`var venit = venit_brut - (cas + cass + somaj + foo());` -- anyway, the function you are creating never returns a value, maybe add `return foo;` to the bottom?

Comment: @josec89 thanks for the suggestions. after I changed the order of the variables and added the 'return foo' at the bottom of the function, the function returns the correct value, but it seems the value is not picked up in the addition operation. I've even assigned the result of 'foo()' to a new var 'deducere' 'var deducere = foo()', to use it in the addition operation, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var deducere0 = ...,
    deducere1 = ...,
    deducere2 = ...,    
    deducere3 = ...,
    deducere4 = ...;


function calculateFoo(selection, venitBrut) {
    if (selection == 0 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
        return 300;
    }
    if (selection == 0 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
        return Math.ceil10(deducere0, 1);
    }
    if (selection == 1 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
        return 400;
    }
    if (selection == 1 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
        return Math.ceil10(deducere1, 1);
    }
    if (selection == 2 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
        return 500;
    }
    if (selection == 2 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
        return Math.ceil10(deducere2, 1);
    }
    if (selection == 3 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
        return 600;
    }
    if (selection == 3 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
        return Math.ceil10(deducere3, 1);
    }
    if (selection == 4 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
        return 800;
    }
    if (selection == 4 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
        return Math.ceil10(deducere4, 1);
    }
    if (document.getElementById("btn_deducere").checked == false) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
};

var foo = calculateFoo(selection, venitBrut);
var venit = venitBrut - (cas + cass + somaj + foo);

console.log(venit);
```

- Make sure `deducere01234` are declared
- Add some `console.log` to check the values returned by the function
- You should change `foo` to a more proper name, I don't really understand what is calculating

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have added the entire code with the modifications you suggested, more or less. Everything worked till the part with the foo function. After I made the changes, it didn't work anymore. I tried to do exactly what you suggested, but I was not sure where to place the CalculateFoo function.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to correct my code. I have re-written my code according to your suggestion but I think something slips my attention as I still get the NaN when the 'var decucere' is used in math operations.

Comment: @CornelIon `NaN` means not a number, my bet is some of your variables are not taking the right value from the html.. check that all the values that come from the html have a right value (`console.log(venit_brut) `)